# Editor for Python in Apache

Tags: python, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am coding some Python on Apache on the Raspberry Pi.  It was ok for the initial simple pages.  But now that I am adding JavaScript, having to do it with:

```
print "<script>var x; ....
```

is sheer torture.

The file is in Python and not html.  Is there a way to reverse the situation, like in ASP or ASP.NET, where the file is expecting html, and I can escape using `<% %>` to write C# code.

Comment: [What exactly are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: To write JavaScript in JavaScript and not embedded in a print statement in Python.

Comment: So then put it in a JavaScript file.

Comment: Good suggestion! But every file now becomes two files.

Comment: What are you talking about? Serve the JavaScript file directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about templating. Take a look at [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) which should allow you do do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like Razer views in MVC.  Will investigate it for the Raspberry Pi.